# What Instruments could have been used to make this 'seashell'-sound?

Tags: instruments, sound

During this [Youtube-Video](https://youtu.be/GC_mV1IpjWA?t=1m50s), the red crab hits the seashells to make an interesting sound. I'd like to reproduce this. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steel drums, or steel pans.  Not a difficult sound to synthesize/sample, it's available on most keyboards etc.   Down to you to play it in style though!

[image]